# Report Filter option returns Zero value

Tags: custom-reports, joined-reports

I tried to generate a report to see the team performance, After running the report I can see the values if my show option is " All accounts". When I change the show option to " My team account" the value is returned zero. How can I see my teammates' Performance? I am at the Manager level so I have access to see the performance report of my teammates as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, you're team members are report you via role hierarchy as well. Standard report filter `My Team account` works as per below statement,

> My team’s accounts: Shows your accounts and accounts owned by all of
> your subordinates in the role hierarchy.

So please check with your team members user roles are coming under your user role.

If it's not, you need to use `Owner Name` field in account report to show your team members accounts with standard filter `All Accounts`(assumed you already have access for your team members account via manual sharing or account sharing rule).

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with the 'owner name' field.